# Not seeing results when using JQuery Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typeahead

I'm trying to use the [JQuery Typeahead plugin](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/overview/) with AJAX but I'm not seeing any search results. The AJAX request returns fine but nothing is displayed.

The example below uses the Open Brewery Search API to find breweries, and the typeahead template has been set to display the name property from the resulting objects.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <form>
            <div class="typeahead__container">
                <div class="typeahead__field">
                    <div class="typeahead__query">
                        <input class="js-typeahead"
                               name="q"
                               type="search"
                               autocomplete="off"
                               placeholder="try: cooper">
                    </div>
                    <div class="typeahead__button">
                        <button type="submit">
                            <span class="typeahead__search-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.js"></script>

<script>

$.typeahead({
    input: ".js-typeahead",
    order: "asc",
    dynamic: true,
    delay: 300,
    template: "<p>{{name}}</p>",
    source: {
        breweries: {
            ajax: function(query) {
                return {
                    url: "https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_name=" + query
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What format does the data you are receiving come in? Is it in the format typeahead is expecting?

Comment: The data are an array of objects, which seems to be what typeahead can work with (in addition to arrays of strings). For example, one of the demos uses http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/user_v1.json?q=e with path = "data.user".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `filter: false`. [See github issue.](https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/issues/305)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <form>
            <div class="typeahead__container">
                <div class="typeahead__field">
                    <div class="typeahead__query">
                        <input class="js-typeahead"
                               name="q"
                               type="search"
                               autocomplete="off"
                               placeholder="try: cooper">
                    </div>
                    <div class="typeahead__button">
                        <button type="submit">
                            <span class="typeahead__search-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.js"></script>

<script>

$.typeahead({
    input: ".js-typeahead",
    order: "asc",
    dynamic: true,
    filter: false,
    delay: 300,
    template: "<p>{{name}}</p>",
    source: {
        breweries: {
            ajax: function(query) {
                return {
                    url: "https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_name=" + query
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```